# Mass of body between curve and plane

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $R$ be the region of the parabloid $z=4-x^2-y^2$ where $z \geq 3$ and let $D$ be the body bounded by $R$ and the plane $z=3$.

Setting $z=z$ I obtain $x^2+y^2=1$ which is the $xy$-projection I assume. The density $p$ is constant $ = 1$

Is this the correct setup?: $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1\int_3^4 1 dzdydx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

You  can conclude your work using cylindrical coordinates: the region is defined by the limits:
$$
3\le z\le 4-r^2 \qquad 0\le r \le 1 \qquad 0\le \theta\le 2\pi
$$

so the volume is given by:
$$
V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \int_3^{4-r^2} r\;dzdrd\theta
$$

Comment: Ah, ofc... getting late... Thank you!!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $dzdrd\theta$ btw, otherwise you end up with 2 variables in the last integral..

Comment: YES! You are right! I edit my typo ...

Answer (score 1):

No, your limits are off. $$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-     \sqrt {(1-X^2)}      }^{    \sqrt {(1-X^2)}   }     \int_3^{4-x^2-y^2} dzdydx$$

That is what you want.

Or you can use polar which is a different story.

Comment: Switching to polar was much easier, as you point out. Thank you for the clarification!